# Getting "erase_size" related error when mounting a jffs2 rootfs into a block device

Tags: kernel, mount, block-device, root-filesystem, modprobe

Trying to mount a jffs2 image into a virtual block device, following [this guide](https://lynxbee.com/how-to-extract-files-from-jffs2-rootfilesystem-image/)

The steps are as follows, summarized:

```
sudo mknod /tmp/mtdblock0 b 31 0
sudo modprobe mtdblock
sudo modprobe mtdram total_size=265536 erase_size=256  # actual total_size used in the command is different as per need
sudo modprobe jffs2
sudo dd if=/home/myuser/Downloads/jffs2File of=/tmp/mtdblock0
sudo mkdir /media/jffs2-extracted 
sudo mount -t jffs2 /tmp/mtdblock0 /media/jffs2-extracted
```

The last step (`mount`) gives an error and nothing gets mounted in `/media/jffs2-extracted`. With `dmesg` I could see these messages (and similar ones) repeated several times:

```
jffs2_scan_eraseblock(): Magic bitmask 0x#### not found at 0x########: 0x#### instead
Old JFFS2 bitmask found at 0x You cannot use older JFFS2 filesystems with newer kernels
```

Then I increased `erase_size` in `sudo modprobe mtdram total_size=265536 erase_size=256` command and the repeated error `jffs2_scan_eraseblock(): Magic bitmask 0x#### not found at 0x########: 0x#### instead` was vanished; but this time got this error:

```
Old JFFS2 bitmask found at 0x You cannot use older JFFS2 filesystems with newer kernels
Cowardly refusing to erase blocks on filesystem with no valid JFFS2 nodes
```

How could figure out the proper value of `erase_size` to use in command? Is it relative to `total_size` in `modeprobe mtdram`? If so, how could I calculate `erase_size` based on `total_size`?

Comment: The erase size is fixed by the hardware i.e. the flash device. By the way, how did you create `/home/myuser/Downloads/jffs2File`?

Comment: @MurrayJensen I've been given the file and trying to mount it. So don't have any technical information about its origin hardware (i.e. erase size)

Comment: @MurrayJensen Should I try to mount on an older version of Linux, according to the message `You cannot use older JFFS2 filesystems with newer kernels`? Currently I'm using kernel `5.16.0`. Maybe trying OS with older kernel could be the workaround?

Comment: You need to confirm the erase_size used when creating the file `jffs2File` and match this value when loading the mtdram module. Note that default erase_size for `mkfs.jffs2` is 64k. You could just try using erase_size of 64 instead of 256 and see what happens.